# XML / XSD - Adding descriptions

Tags: xml, xsd, documentation, editor

With XSD I can make sure that an XML file is valid, but is there also a way, using XSD, to attach informations to elements and properties so that a software that would open the XML and XSD file would be able to display that description to the user when he clicks on the element being described?

Comment: You are probably looking for the [annotation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256102%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) element.

Answer (score 8):

You're describing the **`xsd:documentation`** element.

Both `xsd:documentation` and `xsd:appinfo` can be included within an `xsd:annotation` element:

- Use `xsd:documentation` to provide meta information to a ***user***.
- Use `xsd:appinfo` to provide meta information to a ***application***.

The [W3C XML Schema Part 0: Primer Second Edition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/) has an introduction to annotations [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#CommVers), where they provide the following example of how to use `xsd:documentation`:

```
<xsd:element name="internationalPrice">
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
         element declared with anonymous type
    </xsd:documentation>
  </xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
           empty anonymous type with 2 attributes
      </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType">
        <xsd:attribute name="currency" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="value"    type="xsd:decimal"/>
      </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Comment: But of course, to find out if any particular editor makes use of this information, you need to check the documentation for that particular editor.

Comment: I can confirm that this does work and give hover tooltips with Red Hat's VSCode XML extension. It uses Lemminx under the hood which is also available for Eclipse, Emacs and Vim.