# Including documentation of element type into XML Schema element?

Tags: xml, xsd, documentation

Can you include the documentation of an XML Schema type into the documentation of an element?  For example, with the schema below, the documentation for the `FirstOption` element should be more or less something like:

```
Enable First Option?

Yes/No Choice
1 = Yes
0 = No
```

- 

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:simpleType name="MyChoice">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Yes/No Choice</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="1">
        <xs:annotation><xs:documentation>Yes</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="0">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>No</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:enumeration>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:element name="Options" >
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="FirstOption" type="MyChoice">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Enable First Option?</xs:documentation>
            <!-- What to write here, to include the documentation of `MyChoice`? -->
          </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no standard, XSD-based way to automatically include or derive a component's documentation from another component's documentation or structure.

- One might consider writing XSLT to generate documentation from an XSD, but the benefit of doing so in the general case is likely limited given the complexity involved.<sup>1</sup>

**See also:** [XML / XSD - Adding descriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28065200/290085)

<sub><sup>1</sup> I've built an automated documentation system in XSLT that documented another system written in XSLT, but hand-written documentation is much more the norm.</sub>